# PHP must be an instance of DateTime, string used in

Tags: mysql, pdo, php-7.4

I am experiencing the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Typed property
> App\Models\User::$created_at must be an instance of DateTime, string
> used in /var/www/html/chapter5/src/Models/UserRepository.php:41 Stack
> trace: #0 /var/www/html/chapter5/src/Models/UserRepository.php(41):
> PDOStatement->fetchAll(8, 'App\Models\User') #1
> /var/www/html/chapter5/public/users.php(8):
> App\Models\UserRepository->findAll() #2 {main} thrown in
> /var/www/html/chapter5/src/Models/UserRepository.php on line 41

Line 41 of UserRepository.php is the SQL query in the following function code:

```
public function findAll() : array {
    return $this->getPDO()->query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, User::class);
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

### Update

User.php `__set()` magic method:

```
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    if ( $name == 'created_at' )
        $this->$name = new DateTime($value);
    else
        $this->$name = $value;
}
```

Comment: Your `App\Models\User` class has a property defined as `DateTime $created_at`, the problem is that you fetch date from MySQL as `string` and when `PDO` tries to map the result set to your `User` object it fails. You need to convert `created_at` coming from MySQL  to `DateTime` object first.

Comment: @Rain: Thank you for your very helpful input. I agree with your assessment completely. Regarding the similar question you linked to, I have been trying a very similar strategy but still unable to resolve the string=>DateTime issue. I added the code from my User.php class __set() magic method in my original question.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? To me, it looks pretty obvious that `__set` fails, as you assign the raw `$value` to `$this->created_at`, directly after assigning a DateTime object to it

Comment: @NicoHaase: The __set method is what I have tried. Very sorry, I made a mistake and left out the else part of the if statement. I have corrected the code.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? It should be pretty simple to use vardump here to check **why** this fails.

Comment: @NicoHaase: Not much to vardump, print_r or VarDumper::dump() when the page output is reading fatal error exactly as outlined in my question above

Comment: Please note as I menthoned in my **Note 1** the property name must not have the same name as the column name in your database. So try changing `created_at` in your `User` to something else like for example `created_at_object` . This is the only way to trigger `__set` method. And change `$this->$name = new DateTime($value);` to `$this->created_at_object = new DateTime($value);`